# react: cannot set state in componentWillMount

Tags: react-native

I'm quite the amateur in react-native and I can't seem to understand something that's happening to my code below: i can log the 'data' inside the Promises on the console without a problem, but when I try to set the states 'liked' and 'likedBack' with this.setState, it seems that they don't really change from the initial ones. This function is called inside `componentWillMount()`. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here? Any tips would be of great help.

```
getMatchesUid= (uid, idPet)=>{
    Ofirebase.database().ref('relationships').child(uid).child('pets').child(idPet).on('value', snap=>{
        const relations = snap.val()
        const allMatchesUid = this.getOverlap(relations.liked,relations.likedBack)
        console.log('allMatches', allMatchesUid)
        this.stateFunction(this.state.matches, allMatchesUid) 
        const promiseliked = allMatchesUid.map(profileUid =>{
            firebase.database().ref('relationships').child(uid).child('pets').child(idPet).on('value', snap=>{
                const matches = snap.val()
                const liked = this.getValue(uid, profileUid, idPet, 'liked')
                return (liked)
            })
            const promiselikedBack = allMatchesUid.map(profileUid=>{
                const likedBack = this.getValue(uid, profileUid, idPet, 'likedBack')
                return (likedBack)
            })
            Promise.all(promiseliked).then(data => 
                this.setState({
                    liked: data,
                }))
            this.setState({
                liked: data
            }))
            Promise.all(promiselikedBack).then(data => this.setState({
                likedBack: data,
            }))
```

Answer (score 2):

First Don't use `componentWillMount()` to setState. `componentWillMount()` is called before the component is intialized (rendered) therefore state cannot be set on an unintialized component, use `componentDidMount()` and set state, checkout the following link for more information regarding this,

https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html